# Como resgatar um chave em um Json usando o Gson (Google)

Tags: json, java-ee, spring

boa noite.

Pela primeira vez estou manipulando um arquivo Json com Java, pois muitos colegas sempre me disseram que fica muito facil de se manipular dados, ainda mais com a biblioteca do Google (Gson).

Bem, uma duvida que me surgiu é a seguinte, como eu posso acessar um chave dentro de um arquivo?

Mais ou menos assim:

Gravei um objeto em uma coluna unica desta forma:

```
{  
   "fileName":"090808_072340.jpg",
   "fileSize":"337 Kb",
   "fileType":"image/jpeg",
   "fileTmpPath":"/tmp/joocebox-img/destination/manolo/090808_072340.jpg"
}
```

No caso, queria trabalhar com a chave "**fileTmpPath**".

Eu consigo fazer um parser dentro deste arquivo com algum metodo do Gson? Ou na hora deserializar eu tenho que ter um bean com os campos e o Gson cuida disso para mim? Restando apenas eu dar um **getFileTmpPath()** por exemplo?

Obrigado e um abraço a todos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode converter em um HashMap e pesquisar através da chave. Apesar de ser interessante criar um bean para poder manipular melhor os dados, como você só quer um campo em específico, converta em HashMap e pegue pela chave. Esta abordagem que usei não usa o GSON, mas é tão simples quanto.

Para converter este JSON:

```
{ 
   "erro": 0,
   "info": "OK",
   "criado_em": "2014-08-29 20:33:47",    
   "url": "http://www.ocaminhodoprogramador.com.br",    
   "id": "llXVL",   
   "migre": "http://migre.me/llXVL",   
   "ping": "FAIL",   
   "consumo_api_hora": 0,  
   "tempo": 0.0077569485   
}
```

Recuperei um link encurtado através de uma API JSON (Migre.me) usando o Jackson, desta forma:

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
    URI uri = new URI("http://migre.me/api.json?");
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    WebTarget target = client.target(uri.toURL().toString()).queryParam("url", "http://www.ocaminhodoprogramador.com.br");
    String conteudo = target.request().get(String.class);
    System.out.println(conteudo);

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    map = mapper.readValue(conteudo, new TypeReference<HashMap<String, String>>() {});
    System.out.println(map.get("migre"));
    }
}
```

Assim eu consegui recuperar o resultado de forma simples, usando a chave em questão. Escrevi este exemplo neste post http://www.ocaminhodoprogramador.com.br/2014/05/encurtando-links-em-java-usando-o.html

Comment: Oi Lucas Polo! Primeiramente obrigado pela ajuda. Era bem isso mesmo o que eu estava atrás. Fiz algumas adaptações no meu código e funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado!